# Node JS how to call a function in a spawned child process (powershell script)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

is there a way to call a function in a spawned child process, a powershell script, from the parent node js script?

node script:

```
const cp = require("child_process");
const psData = cp.spawn
("powershell -executionpolicy bypass  ./powershell-script.ps1", [], {
    shell: "powershell.exe",
});
```

powershell script:

```
function psDoSomething{
    # do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no builtin way for Node to call specific functions in a subprocess. You could pass arguments to your PS script if that would help, or you could spawn/exec another PS script, but Node doesn't know or care about Powershell (or Python, or Shell, or any other language in a spawned/execed script). If you need that functionality, you could try one of the Powershell-related packages on NPM.

Edit: OP suggested in a comment using `stdin.write` on the child process, and listening to STDIN in the subprocess, which is an interesting idea. I don't use Powershell, but here's how that could work using Bash:

```js
const bashSession = require('child_process').spawn('./foo.sh')
bashSession.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')
bashSession.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
bashSession.stdin.write('someFunc\n')
bashSession.stdin.end()
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

doThing() {
    echo We made it here
}

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == someFunc ]]; then
        doThing
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Having your subprocess listen to everything on stdin could create problems, but the same concept could be used with a designated file, or with a TCP socket.

Comment: I reckon arguments can only be passed when the child process is spawned so this won't work for my purposes. I've read a bit about childprocess.stdin.write("...") and was wondering if I could add a function to the ps script that will listen to the stdin and trigger the doSomething function when a key word is written from the node script, is this possible?

Comment: @bitbar Yes, that would work, and that's a good idea that I totally didn't even think of. Editing my post.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're looking to do is **a *one-time call* to a function defined inside your PowerShell script**, the following should do:

```js
let child = require('child_process').spawn(
  'powershell', 
  [
    '-noprofile', '-executionpolicy', 'bypass', '-c', 
    '. ./powershell-script.ps1; psDoSomething'
  ],
  // In this simple example, pass the child process' output
  // streams directly through to this process' output streams.
  { stdio: 'inherit' }
)
```

- The above uses [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, with its `-c` / `-Command` parameter to process a given snippet of PowerShell code.
- Since the function to invoke is defined inside the `./powershell-script.ps1` script, that script must be [dot-sourced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) in order to load the function definition into the caller's scope.
- Thereafter, the function can be invoked.

---

If you're **looking to spawn a PowerShell child process to which you can iteratively feed commands for execution *later, on demand*, via *stdin*** - in other words: to **create a *programmatically controlled* REPL** - you'll need a solution whose fundamentals are outlined in [Zac Anger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649846/45375), based on spawning the PowerShell child process with `-c -` (`-Command -`), namely as  `powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -c -`

- Caveat: Sending a command spanning *multiple lines* must be terminated with *two* newlines; see [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223) for details.

```
let child = require('child_process').spawn(
    // Start PowerShell in REPL mode, with -c - (-Command -)
    'powershell',
    [
        '-noprofile', '-executionpolicy', 'bypass', '-c',
        '-' // Start PowerShell as a REPL
    ]
)

// Connect the child process' output streams to the calling process',
// so they are *passed through*.
// Note: Using { stdio: 'inherit' } in the .spawn() call instead 
// would prevent using child.stdin.write() below.
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

// Dot-source the file that defines the function.
// Note the double \n to ensure that PowerShell recognizes the end of the command.
child.stdin.write('. ./powershell-script.ps1\n\n')
// Now you can invoke it. 
child.stdin.write('psDoSomething\n\n')
// ... pass additional commands, as needed.
// End the session.
child.stdin.write('"Goödbyə!"\n\n')
child.stdin.end()
```

**Character-encoding note:**

- `child.stdin.write()` sends UTF-8-encoded strings by default (you can change the encoding with `child.stdin.setEncoding()`, as shown in Zac's anwer).
- For PowerShell *on Windows* to interpret UTF-8-encodes string correctly and to
  also make it output UTF-8 itself, the current console's code page must be `65001` *beforehand* - run `chcp` to verify. If it isn't:

  - If your Node.js program runs from a `cmd.exe` session, run the following first:

    ```
     chcp 65001
    ```
  - If it runs from a PowerShell session, run the following first:

    ```
     $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8encoding]::new()
    ```
- On *Unix*-like platforms, PowerShell fortunately *defaults* to UTF-8.

Comment: how do I invoke the function? 
child.stdin.write("psDoSomething"); does not work, although the ps script get's the text.

Comment: @bitbar, the `; psDoSomething` part in my code snippet invokes the function. If you do want to use the stdin-based approach, you must submit `. ./powershell-script.ps1` as the _first_ command.

Comment: if I understand correctly '. ./powershell-script.ps1; psDoSomething' invokes psDoSomething once, i.e. when the child is spawned. What if the child script has a while true loop, how would I repeatedly call the psDoSomething within the same child process? e.g.: 

`function psDoSomething {
  Write-Output "func invoked from node js script"
}

while ($true) {#some other routines}`

Comment: With the stdin approach, there's no need for a loop: Launch the process with `powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -c -`, then feed all commands to execute via stdin, starting with `. ./powershell-script.ps1`, after which you can send `psDoSomething`

Comment: thanks for your help and insights! I've decided to stick with **psData.stdin.write("some text or special char\n");** in the node script and in the ps: `$textFromNode = Read-Host if ($textFromNode -eq "some text or special char") { psDoSomething }.` This will allow me to invoke psDoSomething on demand. (this comment was edited)

Comment: I found another way to call a function in a ps script from nodejs by using the & call operator:

nodejs script:

    function nodejsFunction() {
        nodejsChildProcess.stdin.write("psFunction\r");
    }

ps script:

    function psFunction {#do something}

    while ($true) {
    $stdin = Read-Host
    & $stdin
    }