# Typescript child_process with Powershell: Only send command output on stdout and avoid command text to be sent again to stdout

Tags: node.js, typescript, powershell, child-process

I want to connect to **Azure ExchangeOnline using Powershell** in our **Typescript** project.

In order to connect to Exchange Online using Powershell, if I am using a `ps` script (let us consider basic auth for now), I would add following commands in script file and execute it:

```
$Username = "exchangeusername@onmicrosoft.domain.com"
$Password = "<exchange-password>"
$encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, 
$encryptedPassword)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credentials
Get-EXOMailBox | ConvertTo-Json
disconnect-ExchangeOnline -confirm:$false
exit
```

> Following command on terminal gives a nice output with the JSON array of Mailboxes

```
pwsh -File <path-to-script> -noni -nol
```

While using typescript, I am using following code:

```
 let powerShellProcess = spawn('pwsh', ['-noni', '-nol'];
 
 powerShellProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
     // print the data here
     console.log("Powershell Returned :: " + data);
 });
```

For all the above commands mentioned, I execute them one-by-one

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** For some internal reasons, I am not allowed to use .ps files to execute the powershell/ exchange scripts, so we have to execute them one by one

So, to connect to exchange and get the Mailboxes I am doing:

```
powerShellProcess.stdin.write("$Username = 'exchangeusername@onmicrosoft.domain.com'"+ "\n);
.....
.....
// and so on...till
powerShellProcess.stdin.write("Get-EXOMailBox | ConvertTo-Json");
```

The problem here is that, the parent process prints all the command texts and other garbage and I am finding it very hard to make sense of the data returned on command execution.

For example, on running the command: `powershellProcess.stdin.write("$Username = 'exchangeusername@onmicrosoft.domain.com'\n");`

> Following is getting printed:

```
Powershell Returned :: PS /Users/user/tutorials/learning-typescript/quick-tests> 
Powershell Returned :: $Username = 'exchangeusername@onmicrosoft.domain.com'

Powershell Returned :: PS /Users/user/tutorials/learning-typescript/quick-tests>
```

Is there any way we can avoid this and let `child_process` send data only when there is some kind of output and also what would be an efficient and elegant way to do so...

Comment: Using `-c -` (`-Command -`) rather than the implied `-File -` should work better, but if you simply want to pass multiple commands known in advance, pass a (multiline) string comprising them all to `-c`. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74650698/45375) helps. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Since I want to connect to ExchangeOnline (which is a costly operation), I want to store the powershell child_process to execute multiple exchangeonline commands

Comment: Understood - the linked answer shows that too.

Comment: Yes, trying to understand it, Will write a simple code to test it.

Comment: Thanks, works for me. We can close for now. Will open another question if required.