# "Eval" functionality in VB6: replace VBScript by Powershell or some other means

Tags: powershell, vb6

Within a VB6 program, I have been using VBScript, to evaluate numerical math-expressions contained in strings.

*(The string are generated by a programmed, string-based, algebraic manipulation algorithm which replaces algebraic variables in a math-expression by numerical values in order to check the results).*

The evaluation of a numerical math-expression string is illustrated in the following code:-

```
vb6
    mathEx$="(1+2)*(5^2)"
    Set ob = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    ob.Language = "VBScript"
    result = ob.eval(mathEx$) '---> 75
```

Now (October 2023) that VBScript is officially to be excluded from future Windows releases,
I wonder whether and how Powershell (or some other means) could be used to provide this functionality (from within the VB6 program)?

**EDIT 1**
This question is NOT answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836703/powershell-how-to-evaluate-a-string) which does not talk about accessing Powershell from VB6 at all.

**EDIT 2**
I have refocussed the question away from just Powerscript to open it up to other tools/methods.

Comment: you can use `Invoke-Expression` (alias `iex`) => `$mathEx = "(1+2)*([math]::Pow(5,2))"; iex $mathEx`

Comment: Related to [VBscript operator precedence inconsistency with VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77323650)

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon
That might be useful...is it Powershell?... how do I access Powershell from within VB6?

Comment: It's really poor practice to use `Eval()` to process math expressions. This is because Eval() is not limited to Math, but opens up _anything_ the language can do, including things that would be security violations. What you really want is a dedicated math parsing library, of which there are several.

Comment: that is how your code is translated in powershell to evaluate a math expression stored in a string. not sure why you want to access powershell from within VB6, powershell can do this quite easily by itself and VB6 is 25 yrs old. this doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Thanks, Yes, I do know that. What I want ideally is the functionality of Eval() but restricted to math expressions - i.e. evaluate a numerical expression held in a string.

Comment: @ Santiago Squarzon My VB6 program is very large and cannot be migrated easilly to another language.  It needs to do do the numeric evaluation as part of a complex procedure. The math expressions are very long and dozens of them need to be done at each run.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn
`dedicated math parsing library, of which there are several` ...If you can point me to any reliable such libraries that can be used by VB6 (as opposed to VB.net) I would appreciate it.  I have found some VB6 source code on the web but it fails with some complicated expressions.

Comment: Calling a `powershell.exe` child process for each evaluation would be prohibitively slow. In principle, you can keep a `powershell.exe` process open and pass it commands repeatedly via stdin (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74650698/45375) for a Nodej.js solution), but I imagine that won't be trivial from VB6. You'd also have to account for PowerShell's different syntax, notably the unavailability of `^` for exponential operations.

Comment: You say that _VBScript_ will be retired, but I wonder if that also applies to the associated COM (ActiveX) components, which aren't VB-specific. In others words: _Perhaps_ `CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")` will continue to work? The [official announcement is woefully terse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features-resources#vbscript).

Comment: While PowerShell does have an [SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart) for in-process use, it is _.NET_-based, and you therefore won't be able to use it in-process from VB6.

Comment: @mklement0
Those are good arguments for not seeking a Powershell solution. Thanks.

Comment: From VB6, there's no point to call vbscript object. Use [Eval()](http://www.tomswebdesign.net/articles/vb6/other.html) function.

Comment: @derloopkat Eval() isnt included in core VB6, it may be I can add reference to an OLB or DLL but don't know which one.

Comment: Here are some native VB6 efforts on expression evaluators -- [Simple math string parser](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?860225-simple-math-string-parser) thread.

Comment: @wqw Its a very interesting thread, in particular the Olaf Schmidt solution. But the problem for me is the lack of rigorous testing - compared to (what I presume happens with) a Microsoft product, which the latest post, in 2018, alludes to (Access Eval()).

Comment: Btw, you can use sqlite (or any other DB) to eval simple math expressions with something like `SELECT (1+2)*(pow(5,2)) AS Result`

Comment: @wqw Yes I was thinking about using the Eval() in MS Access but I don't know the right library file to reference.  And I'm not familiar with acessing other DB's from VB6. Also I'd prefer to use `^` for power expressions, as in VB6 rather than `pow(a,b)`.

Comment: @steveOw, per https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=275908 it is `Microsoft Access Object Library` (cannot verify this myself). But can you assume that all machines that run your application have MS Access installed? Is it possible to bundle just this library for the `.Eval()` functionality? Again, I would look into whether the `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl` control will actually be removed along with VBScript. What's the status of JScript, which can use this control too? (I know it's been disabled in the _browser_, but will it be removed altogether, like VBScript?)

Comment: @mklement0
Good points to which I can't provide firm answers.  For now, I am liking wqw's JET solution which required no further References beyond the 6 already ticked (which as far as I can remember were the minimal set selectable at VB6 installation time) namely:- VBA6.DLL, msvbvm60.dll\3, VB6.OLB, stdole2.tlb, msstdfmt.dll, msdatsrc.tlb.

Comment: Are you abandoning the powershell premise of this question?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Good point. I have obtained useful advice so the original question sensu stricto is only of academic interest to me. I could change the title I suppose, or I could retract my acceptance of the only offered answer and leave the question as is.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I would say remove the PS element and leave the question worded in a more open way... that allows for the good existing answer and maybe something else will come along also. Its an interesting topic!

Comment: @StayOnTarget I have gone with with your advice, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple `Eval` function which uses JET engine (MS Access) expression evaluator to do the job

```
Option Explicit

Private Function Eval(sExpression As String) As Variant
    Static oConn        As Object
    Dim sConnStr        As String
    
    If oConn Is Nothing Then
        sConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Environ$("TEMP") & "\~eval.tmp"
        On Error Resume Next
        CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog").Create sConnStr
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        oConn.Open sConnStr
    End If
    With oConn.Execute("SELECT " & sExpression)
        Eval = .Fields(.Fields.Count - 1).Value
    End With
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Debug.Print Eval("5 AS x, 2 AS y, sin(1+2)*(x^y)")
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work fine most of the time, but my VB6 program/IDE crashed one time.  I will test it more tomorrow.

Comment: Did some more testing and it works well for my prog. Mostly it gives the same results as using VBScript, but sometimes it returns decimal format while VBS returns scientific format. VBS always returns single precision but sometimes Jet returns double precision e.g. for "(40/995.791142760368)".  Overall it seems fine for my needs and no need to link any further libraries. Thankyou very much!